# Using Mule Anypoint, I want to achieve functionality without flow-ref

Tags: java, mule, anypoint-studio

I want to write a java file to control the business flow of mule message,
I do not want to use flow-ref module.

How can I achieve it? Below is my mule xml segment.

```
    <flow name="gtrfsettleFlow">
    <wmq:inbound-endpoint queue="PINOSAY"  doc:name="WMQ"/>
    <component class="com.hsbc.gtrf.settle.esb.Rout" doc:name="Java"/>
    <flow-ref name="flow2" metadata:id="0ec4db90-8b8c-476b-8186-cfc6b015435c"     doc:name="re"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
    <sub-flow name="flow1">
    <wmq:outbound-endpoint queue="PINOSAY"  doc:name="WMQ" connector-ref="WMQ"/>
    <logger message="this is flow1" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </sub-flow>
    <sub-flow name="flow2">
    <logger message="now is flow 2" level="INFO" doc:name="Copy_of_Logger"/>
    </sub-flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can develop java class implementing Callable interface. Where you can access MuleContext (Event, MuleMessage, Payload and properties). Please refer following link for more details

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/developing-components#customizing-the-message-flow-behavior